# FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create') run 2 times when create a comment from a facebook comment web plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, facebook-graph-api

I want to call an ajax 1 time function whenever someone create a comment on the facebook comment plugin. But the sever call the ajax function twice.

I have already looked up for a day but nothing can help me.

here is my code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function fb() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function () {
        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/comment/',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'id': $('#fbcomment').attr('data')
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: () => {

            }
        });
    });

};
```

Here is my facebook js (I put it before `<body>`):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function (d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/vi_VN/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
```

my `urls.py` link:

```
re_path(r'^ajax/comment/$', views.Action.comment, name='comment'),
```

here is the view:

```
    def comment(request):
        id = int(request.POST.get('id'))
        film = get_object_or_404(Film, pk=id)
        film.comment = film.comment + 1
        film.save()
        return JsonResponse(id, safe=False)
```

Please help me.
sorry for my poor english.

[This is what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuV9u.jpg)

Comment: probably not the problem, but where´s your FB.init call?

Comment: If this is actually cross-domain, then there _should_ be two requests - the first one would be the CORS _preflight_ request. Go check what the request method is in each case.

Comment: yeah, you should really check if the ajax call itself is visible 2 times, or if the subscribe callback gets called 2 times already.